# Euler-method implementation

Tags: differential-equations, homework, broken-code

How can I implement this pseudocode in Mathematica?

Algorithm:

```
(* input: f, x0, xmax, y0, n  *)

h = (xmax-x0)/n;
u[1] = x0;
v[1] = y0;
For i = 2,n+1:
    u[i] = u[i-1] + h;
    v[i] = v[i-1] + h * f( u[i-1] , v[i-1] );
End for.
Return {{u[1],v[1]},{u[2],v[2]},...,{u[n+1],v[n+1]}};
```

This is my take on it but it's not working properly.

```
MyEuler[f, x0, xmax, y0, n] = Module[{},
  h = (xmax - x0)/n;
  u[1] = x0;
  v[1] = y0;
  For[i = 2, i <= n + 2, i++,
    u[i] = u[i - 1] + h;
    v[i] = v[i - 1] + h*f (u[i - 1], v[i - 1]);]
   Table[{u[k], v[k]}, {k, 1, n + 1}]]
```

Comment: `f (u[i - 1], v[i - 1])` should probably be `f[u[i - 1], v[i - 1]]` if `f` is a function. And why end your loop at at `n+2` instead of `n+1` is a difference, but perhaps an unimportant one. Other than that, read a good introductory text on how to program Mathematica. You aren't taking good advantage of its features, other than  its quasi-ability to pretend to be C or Java.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(22042)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22042), [(22413*)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22413), [(41783)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41783), [(43623)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43623), [(206106)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/206106), especially (22413).

Comment: Further, arguments of a function are defined by underscore like: `MyEuler[f_,x0_, ....]

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that Euler method is already implemented into the standard `NDSolve` function and can be fixed by the option `Method`? It is just to make sure that we understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes I am aware,but my teacher specifically told us to solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several syntactical mistakes in your code.

1. Function arguments are missing an underscore:

`MyEuler[f_, x0_, xmax_, y0_, n_]`

2. You should use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`, that is: you are missing a colon:

`MyEuler[f_, x0_, xmax_, y0_, n_] :=`

3. Calling a function requires square brackets, not round ones:

`f[u[i - 1], v[i - 1]]`

4. Separate `For` from `Table` by the additional semicolon:

`For[ ... ]; Table[ ... ]`

Put all of this together, and the code should work:

```
MyEuler[f_, x0_, xmax_, y0_, n_] := Module[{},
  h = (xmax - x0)/n;
  u[1] = x0;
  v[1] = y0;
  For[i = 2, i <= n + 2, i++,
   u[i] = u[i - 1] + h;
   v[i] = v[i - 1] + h*f[u[i - 1], v[i - 1]]
   ];
  Table[{u[k], v[k]}, {k, 1, n + 1}]
  ]

f[x_, y_] := x + y;

MyEuler[f, 0, 1, 0, 3]

(* {{0, 0}, {1/3, 0}, {2/3, 1/9}, {1, 10/27}} *)
```

Comment: We could put `h = (xmax - x0)/n, u, v}` inside the currently empty 1st argument of `Module`. And given that `u` and `v` are given initial values named `x0` and `y0`, it would be sensible to change indexing to begin with `0` instead of `1` and to then run `i` only up to `n`.

Comment: @murray, yes, certainly there can be several improvements of the code (as pointed out in other answers). But since it looks like the OP is a beginner in Mathematica, I tried to make only the most necessary changes to make the code work.

Answer (score 6):

In a functional style, I recommend [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html), the key trick of which is to properly define an iteration function to be used repeatedly via pure/anonymous [`Function (&)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html). And more can be found out in @MichaelE2 's comments.

```
Clear[myEuler]
myEuler[f : (_Symbol | _Function), x0_Real, xmax_Real, y0_Real, n_Integer] :=
Module[{h = (xmax - x0)/n, iterate},
    iterate = # + h {1, f @@ #} &;
    NestList[iterate, {x0, y0}, n]
]
```

Note that, considering the numeric nature of the problem, here I set explicitly type checking for each argument of `myEuler`. The consequence is that unless all the type checking returns `True`, `myEuler` will refuse to run. In this way would it be disentangled with MMA's symbolic ability to some extend, which is actually not needed here.

As an example, I set $ f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2, x_0 = 0., x_\text{max} = 1., y_0 = .1 $, and $ n = 100 $, and get the result plotted as below:

[image]